# sql: how to select all records with field set to 0 and set the value of that field to one

Tags: sql

Is this possible in one SQL statement?
I pointer to a nice SQL tutorial on the subject is also appreciated.
I know I can use a command like `SELECT * FROM MYTAB WHERE MYFIELD = 0`
and then use a server script to go through the result and `UPDATE MYFIELD`
 of the result rows.

Comment: Everybody got it (except me). The result is: Query executed OK, 5 rows affected. I'll accept one of the first 3 answers later. Hopefully one with a pointer to the concise tutorial on complex queries?

Comment: Just check the manual of your DBMS, it will show the *complete* syntax. If you are learning SQL then you have to also learn how to read and understand the manual of the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Next lesson: it's called columns in the SQL/dbms world, not fields. (Fields are for excel users...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

`UPDATE MYTAB SET MYFIELD=1 WHERE MYFIELD=0`

**Edited to Add:**

If you are interested in SQL tutorials, a lightweight one that has the nice feature of allowing you edit and run SQL commands in the webpage to see how they work is from w3schools here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 1):

If you can execute a query to read the data you should also be able to write the data;

`UPDATE MYTAB SET MYFIELD = 99 WHERE MYFIELD = 0`

- [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)
- [UPDATE Statement (Oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm)
- [UPDATE Syntax (MySQL)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)
- [UPDATE Statement (PostgreSQL)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE query..

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET FIELD = 1
WHERE FIELD = 0
```

I think it should be as simple as:

```
UPDATE MYTAB
SET MYFIELD = 1
WHERE MYFIELD = 0
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to execute a `SELECT` query when your purpose can be solved by a simple `UPDATE` query? It seems that you want to switch the flag column of your table.

> how to select all records with field set to 0 and set the value of
>   that field to one

Use below query.

```
Update MYTAB 
set MYFIELD=1 
Where MYFIELD=0
```

This query will find all records where `MYFIELD` is set to **0** and will update all those records with value **1**.

You can browse thru following links to learn advance SQL.

- [SQLCourse2.com](http://www.sqlcourse2.com/)
- [SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)
- [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)

Comment: I was not aware of the WHERE clause in the UPDATE command. Was sick on the day when it was taught. :-)

Comment: yes, it worked. I've added a note that it did in the edit of the question.